# Is there a way using the fish shell environment to list functions defined in the current script?

Tags: function, fish

I'm looking for a sort of mix between `set -l` and `functions`, like a `functions -l`.

This would help me more efficiently update my script in the future, but won't need to remember to edit certain areas manually to tell that part of the script that the functions are recognized, and another part that tells the user which ones are defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way at present to do that. The resolution to [issue #3295](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3295) might provide the necessary mechanism to do what you want.